# output in html rails passed value

Tags: ruby-on-rails

i have the fallowing code :

```
<%= link_to 'Get started now !',play_path ,:alert => 'Eroare bla bla bla',:notice => 'E ok'  %>
```

How can i output in html on the 'play_path' page the :alert value ?

my controller looks like this

```
  def index
    @alert = flash[:alert]
    @notice = flash[:notice]

    end
```

and in my view i have

```
<%=@alert %>
```

It just doesn't display anything , but if in my controller i modify `@alert = :blablabla` , it displays in my view "blablabla"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your link:

```
<%= link_to 'Get started now !',play_redirect_path ,:alert => 'Eroare bla bla bla',:notice => 'E ok'  %>
```

In your controller

```
def redirect
   redirect_to play_path, :alert => params[:alert]
end

def show
   @alert = flash[:alert]
end
```

In your view

```
<%= @alert %>
```

You will also need to set up a route in your config routes.rb

```
match "play/redirect" => "plays#redirect"
```

Comment: i've added in my controller index def  @alert = flash[:alert] @notice = flash[:notice] , and when i use this code : <%=@alert %> it doesn't do anything :-?? if i do this in my controller @alert = :blablabla , the text blablabla is displayed :-??

Comment: why can't i just do @alert = flash[:alert] in the controller ? ( it doesn't seem to work )

Comment: You can, I have just tested it.  Are you doing <%=@alert %> in your view?  If that is not working, please post the code for your related views and controllers.

Comment: The issue is that flash notices are a property of redirect_to and not link_to.  That is why in my initial answer, I mentioned :alert being a key in the params hash.  If you want to use it in your link_to, then it should link to a controller action which redirects to the play_path with the flash notice attached.  I'll update my answer to reflect this.

Comment: i've kind of suspected this was the problem as i googled it , thanks  :)